# Excel Formula For Subtotal is not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

My Data Range is `J52:L60`.

First formula in `K52` is working Properly.

```
=IF(J52="",SUM(J52:INDEX(J52:$J$60,MATCH(TRUE,(J53:$J$60=""),0))),"")
```

Second one in `L53` producing Running total instead of Subtotal.

```
=IF(J53="",SUM(J53:INDEX($J$52:J$60,MATCH(TRUE,(J$52:J$60<>""),0))),"")
```

[image]

Only problem is, the second formula has to produce 18 in place of 27.

Answer (score 3):

Your second one does not need to be an array formula:

```
=IF(J53="",SUM($J$52:$J53)-SUM($L$52:$L52),"")
```

This takes the running total of column J and subtracts any values already calculated in column L.

Comment: Scott its working,,, is any possibility to correct my Formula,,, if any one here any clue or idea please suggest me the corrections for the Array formula NOT Working properly.

Comment: You do not want to use MATCH, You will need to use LARGE(IF()) or AGGREGATE().  The MATCH is returning the first blank always. which is J52.  so your formula will always start with the range there.  @RajeshS When a standard formula will work one should avoid array formulas, which cause larger drains on calculations.

Comment: Could you please create one example using Large(if()).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're attempting to create a subtotal between blanks, the second formula will work as:

```
=IF(J53="",SUM(J53:INDEX(J$52:J52,MATCH(2,1/($J$52:J52=""),1))),"") {Array Entered}
```

The Match(2,1/(... is a reverse match which finds the last blank cell in the range. Since the range it's checking ends one row above, it will find the previous blank, which then combines with the current row reference to bookend the sum function.

Comment: Nayrb,, its working & I got the reason why was not working,,.